# Asp.Net Core Generate Image file dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, asp.net-core, .net-core

How is it possible to generate an image all in the controller and return it as an image file? For example if link is:

```
www.test.com/generate?width=100&height=50&color=red
```

This shall generate 100x50 red image and return it, and if I set this link as a source of Image View on front, it shall draw that image. It shall work as a service which does not have any connection to UI either HTML or other platforms like iOS UIImageView and Android ImageView.

Comment: @Mat thanks but the question seems ok for me and I answered my question, and when someone googles same problem, he may find this 'downvoted' question useful

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I managed to draw using System.Drawing and System.Drawing.Drawing2D - Graphics class

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

var pen = new Pen(lineColor, widthLine);

graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(bgColor), new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
```

and graphics has all necessary methods for drawing, after drawing finished use the bitmap to create image file and return HttpResponseMessage from ASP net action

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    bitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.ToArray());
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
    return result;
}
```

This was all I wanted and not the useless down votes :)

Comment: In a new .net core web app, I also had to install [`System.Drawing.Common`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common)  Also, don't forget to dispose of all those resources (`Bitmap`, `Graphics`, `Pen`, `SolidBrush`)